# How to make select2 dropdown height the same as inline button?

Tags: bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

I'm trying to size the height of a dropdown to be the same as a button next to it, but I don't know where to apply the style, or even if its possible.

```
<div class="row m-3">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="input-group">
        <select id="theSelect">
        <option value="1">Number One</a>
        <option value="2">Number Two</a>
        <option value="3">Number Three</a>
      </select>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Add</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/capnanon/pen/xxKeyGO) showing the issue.

Comment: https://angel-vladov.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/4.0.5.html

Comment: @User863 I've seen this. Could you elaborate what you mean by linking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following CSS to control the height or the width :

```
.select2-selection__rendered {
    line-height: 31px !important;
}
.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
    height: 35px !important;
}
.select2-selection__arrow {
    height: 34px !important;
}
```

the classes `.select2-container` ,`.select2-selection--single`,`.select2-selection__rendered`,`.select2-selection__arrow` are being rendered when you initiate the `select2` via jquery .